# Do (modern) audio recordings exist for the sound of Ancient Egyptian, Ancient Coptic, or other ancient languages?

Tags: ancient-history

Here are [audio recordings](https://www.soas.ac.uk/baplar/recordings/) of the Akkadian or other Babylonian languages. They are of modern people reenacting it, but it sounds great. Good intro to the real ancient world.

Do any audio recordings similar to that exist for these languages?

- Ancient Egyptian
- Ancient Demotic
- Ancient Coptic
- Ancient Gothic
- Old English
- Old Norse
- Amharic (Book of Enoch)
- Avestan
- Ancient Greek
- Ancient Latin
- Tibetan

I only found [this](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/museums-static/digitalegypt/sound/index.html), but it's basically vocabulary words. I am looking for a full reading of something. Also, not looking for chanting with music behind it, unless that's all that really exists.

Comment: Linguistics se might be a better bet

Comment: For Latin, Youtube is full of readings of Catullus (e.g. https://youtu.be/r7--agTtb5M?t=6) or the Aeneid (e.g. https://youtu.be/CmDfdnktMcI?t=60), but just with a search

Comment: You could probably find a recording of at least part of Beowulf in Old English. Icelandic is descended from Old Norse; according to my Linguistics professor, it's still pretty much Old Norse today. If you want something oddball, look for Occitan, an extinct language of France.

Comment: search for a language name on youtube. there are various old norse / old english / latin/greek stuff. e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFX1nbD3dV0 (Interview with an Anglo-Saxon in Old English). It is also easy to find latin and greek music https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoLmw-7YiyXJA6Ma0DvAzhg (although it may be eclesiastic latin or modern greek, many musics are medieval at least). A search for 'oldest music babylon' got stuff like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUcTsFe1PVs (sumerian)

Comment: heck, there are so many medieval music on youtube and medieval lyrics on the net (not just gregorian, secular music too), that your question only start to get interesting if you focus on classical antiquity or earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was getting too long for a comment, but Cambridge University's [ASNC Spoken Word](https://www.asnc.cam.ac.uk/spokenword/) site has examples of Old English and Norse texts being read. (They also have an example of Insular Latin, some Welsh and Cornish texts, medieval Irish Gaelic, and some continental Celtic language texts).  I understand that more texts are likely to be added over time.

- At the time of writing, the Old English (Anglo-Saxon) texts are just
  two passages from the Battle of Malden poem.
- The Old Norse examples are a passage from *Gylfaginning*, and an
  excerpt from *The Saga of Hrolf kraki*.  The latter is offered in 2
  versions, with one being read more slowly:

> "... in order to allow listening to specific phrases and pronunciation practice."

---

In each case, the text and translation are provided, with an audio file that can either be played in the browser or downloaded..